# Need SQL to find records with repeating values across separate columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a fairly simple table that looks something like this:

```
CID     ID2     ID3     ID4
001     002     002     002
002     003     003     003
003     003     010     010
004     099     080     080
005     100     080     081
006     101     043     009
007     017     013     009
008     092     012     009
```

I am trying to write an SQL query (currently in MS Access but I should be able to adopt whatever) that will identify all of the values in CID where any of the values in ID2, ID3 or ID4 repeat within their own column and the associated counts of repeat values.  I can do this fairly easily with one column but I'm too much of a noob to figure out how to get where they repeat in different columns.

My expected result from the table above would be:

```
CID     Count
002     2
003     2
004     2
005     2
006     3
007     3
008     3
```

CID's 002 and 003 share the same ID2, CID's 004 and 005 share the same ID3 and CID's 006, 007 and 008 all share the same ID4.

So far I have done this, which works to get the counts just from ID2:

```
SELECT tbl.CID, Count(*) AS COUNTIDs FROM tbl GROUP BY tbl.ID2 HAVING Count(*)>1;
```

Thanks for looking and your help!

Comment: OK, I've editted the post to include this.  I didn't bother because it doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I base my answer in SQL Server.
You should UNPIVOT your table. This way you will have all your columns as rows.
Then, with your last query will have the result you desire.

The problem is Access does not have this function included. Then you need to do this:

```
SELECT my_col
INTO tbl
FROM (
    SELECT CID as my_col
    FROM TABLE
         UNION
    SELECT ID2 as my_col     
    FROM TABLE
         UNION
    SELECT ID3 as my_col
    FROM TABLE
         UNION
    SELECT ID4 as my_col
    FROM TABLE
) as auxiliar
```

And your query will show you the result:

```
SELECT tbl.my_col, Count(*) AS COUNTIDs 
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY tbl.my_col 
HAVING Count(*)>1;
```